# Просьба помочь разобраться с r-value и l-value значениями в шаблонах

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Почему код №1 компилируется, а код №2 нет
Код №1

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T> void my_swap(T&& first, T& second){T buf=second; second=first; first=buf; }
template<typename T> void my_swap(T& first, const int second){first=second; }

int main()
{
    int a=1;
    int b=2;
    cout << a << " " << b << endl;
    my_swap(a,b);
    cout << a << " " << b << endl;
    my_swap(a,10);
    cout << a << " " << b << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Код №2

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T> void my_swap(T& first, T& second){T buf=second; second=first; first=buf; }
template<typename T> void my_swap(T& first, const int second){first=second; }

int main()
{
    int a=1;
    int b=2;
    cout << a << " " << b << endl;
    my_swap(a,b);
    cout << a << " " << b << endl;
    my_swap(a,10);
    cout << a << " " << b << endl;
    return 0;`введите сюда код`
}
```

С моей точки зрения правильно : T& first, T&& second

Comment: Код 1 компилируется - потому что все все вызовы обслуживаются второй функцией, как более конкретной.

Во втором случае второй вызов однозначен - с `const int`. А вот первый может быть и тем, и другим, без каких-либо приведений - вот и получается неоднозначность... *"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*

Comment: Если код не компилируется, то команду и лог сборки следует приводить прямо в вопросе. *"С моей точки зрения правильно : T& first, T&& second"* - к чему это относится, в коде же такой перегрузки нет? И ни в одном случае аргумент не будет rvalue.